# Is this proof claiming that P(A union B) does not equal P(A) union P(B) correct?

Tags: proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets and $\mathbb{P}(A)$ the power set of $A$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) \neq \mathbb{P}(A) \cup \mathbb{P}(B)$ for some $A$ and $B$.

Let $A$ be the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and $B$ the set $\{4,5,6\}$. Then $|A \cup B| = |A|+|B| = 6$ since A and B are disjoint. And so  $|\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)| = 2^6$. On the other hand the size of $\mathbb{P}(A) \cup \mathbb{P}(B)$ is at most $|\mathbb{P}(A)|+|\mathbb{P}(B)| = 2^3+2^3=2^4$. Since the two sets don't have the same size, they cannot equal.

Is this correct?

Comment: You're proof is perfectly fine. Giving a good counterexample is a very nice way to disprove something

Comment: Also, notice for example that $A\cup B\in \mathbb{P}(A\cup B)\setminus \mathbb{P}(A)\cup \mathbb{P}(B)$ - unless $A\cup B\subset A$ or $A\cup B\subset B$.

Comment: I thought $\mathbb{P}(A)=\{X:X\subset A\}$...

Comment: @Did the implication here is that he means $\Bbb P(A)$ as being the *power set* of $A$.  You may be thinking he meant the probability of $A$.  Indeed, I am more familiar with seeing power set notated as $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and probability as $Pr(A)$, but to each their own.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oops, silly me. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -2):

What you said is correct but does not prove the theorem. You only proved that the equation is not in general true. The theorem is that the equation is always false. You need a more general cardinality argument.

Comment: "*The equation is always false*" is incorrect.  Take $A=B$ for example.  Then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)=\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)=\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$

Comment: @Jmoravitz Ah yes I see. Even interpreting the task literally, it can still be afforded the graciousness of being possible.